# If $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{y-1}$ is a prime number then how prove that y is also a prime number?

Tags: number-theory

If $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{y-1}$ is a prime number then how prove that $y$ is also a prime number?
$x$ and $y$ are natural numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's simpler than that. Suppose $y$ is composite, $y=ab$. Then
$$ 1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{ab-1} = (1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{b-1})(1+x^b+x^{2b}+\cdots +x^{(a-1)b}) $$
and therefore the value of the LHS is composite too.